# Python: get stdout from background subprocess

Tags: python, linux, shell, background, subprocess

i'm trying to get informations of a network interface on a linux machine with a python script, i.e. 'ifconfig -a eht0'. So i'm using the following code:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('ifconfig -a eth0', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.wait()
output = proc.communicate()[0]
```

Well if I execute the script from terminal with

```
python myScript.py
```

or with

```
python myScript.py &
```

it works fine, but when it is run from background (launched by crontab) without an active shell, i cannot get the output.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you do with `output` to see if it worked or not (whether in background or in active shell)? Do you save it to a file? If so, does the file get created but with no content or no file at all?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you don't set `shell=True`, eg `proc = subprocess.Popen(['ifconfig', '-a', 'eth0'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` ?

Comment: the output is sent to a remote db, and when it is run from terminal i can read the data. While if i use `shell=False` i get this error `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: If you don't use `shell=True` you **must** pass the command line as a list, as shown in my previous comment.

Comment: @PM2Ring i have used the list to pass the command and it raised this exception `[Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to used "screen"?

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('screen ifconfig -a eth0', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I'm not sure that it can work or not.

Comment: If you're not sure that it should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: SO Users with less than 50 reputation cannot comment on other people's posts.

Comment: Yes, I can not comment. I met the same issue before. the solution worked for me. But I am not sure that it works for others

Answer (score 0):

Try proc.stdout.readline() instead of communicate, also stderr=subprocess.STDOUT in subprocess.Popen() might help. Please post the results.

Comment: Launching the script from terminal gives `eth0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:b2:23:a4:12:1e` instead of the full output, and if run by cron it gives again empty string.

Comment: I suggest you to use proc.communicate then. Have you tried redirecting the standard error to output with 2>&1 ?

Comment: also, try invoking a script from crontab and redirecting the output at the line where you invoke the script (might be related, I'm not a strong crontab user [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52330/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-from-within-cron)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem, i guess that the system is not able to recognize the function `ifconfig` when executed by the crontab. So adding the full path to the subprocess allows the script to be executed properly:

```
`proc = subprocess.Popen('/sbin/ifconfig -a eth0',shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 proc.wait()
 output = proc.communicate()[0]`
```

and now i can manage the output string.

Thanks